# Poisson Gamma Mixture = Negative Binomially Distributed?

Tags: distributions, modeling, negative-binomial-distribution, marketing, compound-distributions

[This paper](http://brucehardie.com/papers/018/fader_et_al_mksc_05.pdf) introduces a model called **"Beta-Geometric / NBD"** which models *"repeat-buying behavior in settings where customer “dropout” is unobserved: It assumes that customers buy at a steady rate (albeit in a stochastic manner) for a period of time, and then become inactive."*

While I understand the "Beta-Geometric" aspects of the model (the number of purchases until a user becomes inactive, with Beta modeling heterogeneity across users), I don't quite get what **NBD** really refers to in this model.

NBD supposedly stands for Negative Binomial, but what's **negative binomial** about this model? I read online that it's related to having a Poisson-Gamma mixture, which this model has, but why? What's the connection between **Negative Binomial** and a **Poisson Gamma** mixture? If that's not the connection, why does the model name emphasize the term NBD?

I list the model assumptions below.

[image]

Related: [Is it possible to understand pareto/nbd model conceptually?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/251506/is-it-possible-to-understand-pareto-nbd-model-conceptually)

Comment: The Negative Binomial is equivalent to a Poisson(λ) distribution, where λ is a random variable, distributed as a gamma distribution with shape = r and scale θ

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are various ways a [negative binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture) can come about. One of them, as [Robert Long comments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479170/poisson-gamma-mixture-negative-binomially-distributed#comment884642_479170), is as a Poisson distribution whose parameter is itself Gamma distributed. [The Wikipedia page gives the derivation of this result.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture) So this covers parts (i) and (ii) of your model.

This is an example of [compound-distributions](/questions/tagged/compound-distributions), which are often also called "mixtures" (e.g. a "Poisson-Gamma mixture" in the present case). [This can be confusing, since a "mixture" has at least one related but distinct meaning in statistics.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/1352)

Answer (score 8):

The negative binomial distribution **is** the Poisson-gamma mixture.  Specifically, it can be established that:

$$\text{NegBin} \bigg( t \bigg| n, \frac{1}{\theta+1} \bigg)
= \int \limits_0^\infty \text{Pois}(t|\lambda) \ \text{Gamma}(\lambda|n, \theta) \ d \lambda.$$

(In this statement the parameter $\theta$ is the rate parameter of the gamma distribution.)  This is a useful algebraic exercise to work through if you are new to these distributions.