# Poisson Distribution Question- Viral Vector Integrations

Tags: poisson-distribution, biostatistics, compound-distributions

The number of viral genomes that integrate in cells follows a poisson distribution (https://www.nature.com/articles/3302270). This assumes every target cell has the same infectivity. How does one model the scenario when the cells may have a difference in infectivity?

Answer (score 0):

If the cells have different infectivity, with a distribution $g$ say over infectivity, the resulting distribution of number of viral genomes (if I am understanding the situation correctly ...) will be a **Poisson mixture (or compound) distribution**, where the Poisson mean $\theta$ itself has the distribution $g$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_probability_distribution)

So the pmf (probability mass function) will be given by
$$  \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
 \P(Y=k) = \int_0^\infty \P_\text{Poisson}(Y=k \mid \theta) g(\theta)\; d\theta 
$$ If $g$ is a Gamma distribution, the result is a negative-binomial distribution, see [Poisson Gamma Mixture = Negative Binomially Distributed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479170/poisson-gamma-mixture-negative-binomially-distributed).